# How to set overflow: hidden; on jQuery Mobile page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm looking to have certain pages in my application have the property overflow:hidden added to them i.e if something doesn't fit on the page then it gets cut off the page and the user can't scroll down. Now the following css works:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem is it cuts off everything on all the pages but I want it just on a specific page. The page I have is called `sellbookpage`. Thus I've used the following css:

```
#sellbookpage{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now I know the css above isn't applied to the page (I inspected the element in the browser). I'm really not sure how to set `overflow:hidden` for just a page in jquery mobile

Comment: `height` is set to `100%`, the div will take the maximum possible height and will cause scroll. You need to set a fixed `height` or `max-height` in order for overflow to work. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/G24RL/

Comment: Omar once again your being a boss